# Is it possible to connect API gateway with node routes in AWS lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have implemented node application with AWSServerlessExpress and deployed in Lambda function. but unable to point API Gateway to node routes. every time I'm getting 404 status.

```
var express = require('express')
, router = express.Router()

router.post('/es', function(request, response){
    response.status(200).send("Lambda is triggered");
    response.end()
})

router.get('/es/csv', function(request, response){
    response.status(200).send("hello");
    response.end()
})

module.exports = router;
```

How can I point API gateway directly to get Or Post route?

Comment: are you able to invoke the routes direcly (with a test message)?

Comment: If I have root route with get http verb like below able send request. Other routes '/es', '/es/csv' are throwing 404 error.
router.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.status(200).send("hello");
    response.end()
})

Comment: As far I know (that may be wrong too) - these routes will not work directly. You can define extra paths in the API manager, specify the lambda (always the root route will be invoked), but in the API manager it is possible to map input extra parameters to the input message. I don't like this so I will try it out myself

Comment: Thanks, gusto2, I checked with ARN links mapping in API Gateway but now I'm facing another invocation issues that might be related to my execution role.

Answer (score 2):

After gone through the AWS documentation I have found a solution to my question. To forward the request from API Gateway to node routes in lambda we have to create a new proxy ({proxy+})resource in API gateway under this resource create any method(based on your requirement).

[image]

I found this answer here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy

Comment: how are you calling this endpoing ? Are you using the Amazon SDK and doing ->invoke, or just a plain curl ?

Comment: I'm just invoking from some other front end frameworks @Scobee