# ClaudiaJs with multi-route ExpressJS app deploying to AWS Lambda and AWS API Gateway

Tags: express, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, claudiajs, claudia.js

I have an ExpressJS project with several routes

```
var app = new express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/car', car);
app.use('/bike', bike);
app.use('/bus', bus);
app.use('/train', train);
app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.render('layout', { title: 'app example' });
});
module.exports = app
```

I have deployed with ClaudiaJS to AWS Lambda and the deployment seems to work.

After that, I am configuring AWS API Gateway to invoke different resource paths in the Lambda Function. What I have found is that it properly works for the root path '/' but when I try to invoke a different resource path from API Gateway I get this error in API Gateway:

```
"You do not have permission to perform this action"
```

Additionally I get this message in the Lambda Function:

```
"The API with ID XXXXXXXXX does not include a resource with path /car having an integration arn:aws:lambda:myzone:XXXXXXXXXXXXX:function:functioname on the GET method."
```

Is this something possible to do currently with ClaudiaJS or even a supported configuration (multiple resource paths) in Lambda functions? Any experience?

---

Update 1: this seems to be possible for AWS Lambdas. See here: [Is it possible to connect API gateway with node routes in AWS lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158423/is-it-possible-to-connect-api-gateway-with-node-routes-in-aws-lambda) Not sure if ClaudiaJS can manage this use case

---

Update 2: ClaudiaJS confirms in their support group https://gitter.im/claudiajs/claudia that deploying a multi-route ExpressJS app to a single AWS Lambda is possible with their product and refers me to https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/serverless-apps-with-node-and-claudiajs/chapter-13/v-5/167 So it looks some config/invokation error on my side

---

Update 3: Managed to invoke successfully 2 routes:

```
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World test!');
});
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});
```

Getting {"message": "Internal server error"} for third route accessing MongoDB on EC2. Looks a permission issue.

Comment: how do you call the AWS Api gateway with specific routes ? Using curl is easy since you just call the URL, but what about using the amazon SDK ? With:    $result = $client->invoke(array(
            'FunctionName' => 'Express-Lambda-Boilerplate',
            'InvocationType' => 'RequestResponse',
        ));
Do you know how can I add the path in here ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this issue had nothing to do with ClaudiaJS.

It just needed to use the internal IP of the EC2, instead the external one, as described here [Invalid permission from Lambda to MongoDB in EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50217469/invalid-permission-from-lambda-to-mongodb-in-ec2/50219616#50219616)